# Magento updating an array through looping it inside foreach

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, magento-1.8

I am working with magento database for getting some tax related things that are applied to the product. So here i got stuck with an array that i am getting through the below query :

```
//Zend style query.
            $select = $db->select()
                    ->from(array('t1' => $tableName1),
                    array('t1.order_id', 't1.item_id', 't1.product_id', 't1.store_id', 't1.price', 't1.tax_amount', 't1.tax_percent',new Zend_Db_Expr('"0" as product_taxclassid')))
                    ->joinLeft(array('t2' => $tableName2),'t1.item_id = t2.item_id')
                    ->joinLeft(array('t3' => $tableName3),'t2.tax_id = t3.tax_id', array(new Zend_Db_Expr('t3.code as tax_calculation_rate_code'),'t3.priority'))
                    ->join(array('t4' => $tableName4),'t3.Code = t4.code',array('t4.tax_calculation_rate_id'))
                    ->where('t1.Order_id = ?',$OrderId)                                             
                    ->where('t1.Item_id = ?',$ItemId);                                                                  
            //Query 
            $result = $db->fetchall($select);

            //return object
            return $result;
```

The above query gives the below result as return :

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (11) { ["order_id"]=> int(75) ["item_id"]=> int(127) ["product_id"]=> int(256) ["store_id"]=> int(4) ["price"]=> string(7) "47.0000" ["tax_amount"]=> string(7) "17.4200" ["tax_percent"]=> string(6) "5.0000" ["product_taxclassid"]=> int(0) ["tax_calculation_rate_code"]=> string(10) "Canada-GST" ["priority"]=> int(0) ["tax_calculation_rate_id"]=> int(3) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (11) { ["order_id"]=> int(75) ["item_id"]=> int(127) ["product_id"]=> int(256) ["store_id"]=> int(4) ["price"]=> string(7) "47.0000" ["tax_amount"]=> string(7) "17.4200" ["tax_percent"]=> string(6) "7.3500" ["product_taxclassid"]=> int(0) ["tax_calculation_rate_code"]=> string(13) "Canada-VC-PST" ["priority"]=> int(1) ["tax_calculation_rate_id"]=> int(10) } }
```

I am trying to update this array before return and the filed i want to update is `product_taxclassid` Which is a integer type. So how can i do so please suggest me so that my returning array could have  `["product_taxclassid"]=> int(0) 100`

Please help me with this & let me know if i am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Everyone I found the answer myself, I m posting the answer for anyone having such type of issue with the query. Here is what I did :

```
$select = $db->select()
                    ->from(array('t1' => $tableName1),
                    array('t1.order_id', 't1.item_id', 't1.product_id', 't1.store_id', 't1.price', 't1.tax_amount', 't1.tax_percent',new Zend_Db_Expr('"0" as product_taxclassid')))
                    ->joinLeft(array('t2' => $tableName2),'t1.item_id = t2.item_id')
                    ->joinLeft(array('t3' => $tableName3),'t2.tax_id = t3.tax_id', array(new Zend_Db_Expr('t3.code as tax_calculation_rate_code'),'t3.priority'))
                    ->join(array('t4' => $tableName4),'t3.Code = t4.code',array('t4.tax_calculation_rate_id'))
                    ->where('t1.Order_id = ?',$OrderId)                                             
                    ->where('t1.Item_id = ?',$ItemId);                                                                  
            //Query 
            $result = $db->fetchall($select);

foreach($result as $result){
  $newArray[] = $result->toArray();
}

foreach($newArray as $key => $value){
   $value['product_taxclassid'] = '100';
  echo $value['product_taxclassid'];
}
```

So thats it, Updated the value what i was searching for.